# Extending LinearLayout Null Reference

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to be able to instantiate a new custom LinearLayout class based on a layout defined in xml.  No matter what I do, at runtime, the LinearLayout and all of my TextViews throw a null reference exception.

transferListRow.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:padding="5dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transferSerial"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transferModel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/transferSite"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/transferDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/delete" />
```

TransferListRow.cs Attempt 1:

```
 sealed class TransferListRow : LinearLayout
 {
    private readonly Context _context;

    public TransferListRow(Context context, string serial, string model, string site)
        :base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

        LayoutInflator inflator = (LayoutInflator) _context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        inflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferListRow, null);

        TextView s = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferSerial);
        s.Text = serial;

        TextView m = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferModel);
        m.Text = model;

        TextView st = (TextView) FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferSite);
        st.Text = site;
    }
}
```

TransferListRow.cs Attempt 2:

```
sealed class TransferListRow : LinearLayout
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public TransferListRow(Context context, string serial, string model, string site)
        :base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) FindViewById(Resource.Layout.transferListRow);

        TextView s = (TextView) layout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferSerial);
        s.Text = serial;

        TextView m = (TextView) layout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferModel);
        m.Text = model;

        TextView st = (TextView) layout.FindViewById(Resource.Id.transferSite);
        st.Text = site;

        AddView(s);
        AddView(m);
        AddView(st);
    }
}
```

End goal would be from my main activity be able to do something like this in a button click event:

```
 mainLayout.AddView(new TransferListRow(this, "serial", "model", "site"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Because you are extending LinearLayout, your layout definded in XML does not need to have a LinearLayout wrapper. Instead use just `<merge>  ... </merge>`.

2) In your constructor you have to call `inflator.Inflate(Resource.Layout.transferListRow, this);`. Please note the **this** parameter. This will inflate all elements defined in your XML into the LinearLayout as children.

3) The framework will notify you in `onFinishInflate()` when inflating is done and the views can be found with `findViewById()`. So, in `onFinishInflate()` you can assign your TextViews to your member variables.

That's it :)

Comment: One little addition though.  For whatever reason, OnFinishInflate() never happens.  So I still had to assign the values of my TextViews in the constructor, but all is working now.

Comment: hm, this is really weird. What programming language are you using? In your code snippets, this is not Java, right?

Comment: It is C#.  I am using a product call Mono for Android that allows you to program Android apps in Visual Studio using C#.

Comment: Is that product open source? Are you able to have a look inside of it? Maybe they are handling this kind of events differently.